# Why does my cryptography python program not work?

Tags: python, cryptography

I am trying to write a program to encrypt and decrypt messages. Here is the traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\notelling\OneDrive\Desktop\pyprojects\crypto.py", line 15, in

f = Fernet(key)
NameError: name 'key' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
if os.path.isfile("encryption.key"):
    file = open("encryption.key", "rb")
    filec = file.read().decode()
else:
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    file = open('encryption.key', 'wb')
    file.write(key.encode()) # The key is type bytes still
    file.close()
    print("Key generated.")
mode = input("Please enter mode (e/d):")
if mode == 'e':
    message = input("What is your message to encrypt?").encode()
    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f.encrypt(message)
    passkey = open("encryptedmsg.txt", "wb")
    passkey.write(encrypted)
    passkey.close()
elif mode == 'd':
    passread = open("encryptedmsg.txt", "rb")
    contents = passread.read()
    f = Fernet(key)
    decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted).decode()
    print("Decrypted message is ", decrypted)
input()
```

Comment: Because `key` is only initialized when the first if condition is `False`. So, if `os.path.isfile("encryption.key")` is True, you won't have a `key` variable. Hence, giving this error

Comment: The variable 'key' is only defined in the else clause, therefore it doesn't exist if the else clause isn't entered. By the way, what are you using the variable 'filec' for? Shouldn't that be 'key'?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to cryptography, but pure Python specific error.

The variable key is assigned in the first 'else' block, line no. 7.

This variable won't available outside that block, unless defined specifically.

More references:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: Python does not have block scope, and those links are about class/instance attributes which are irrelevant.